# Is there a way to reference the Java class for a Kotlin top-level function?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to load a resource in a top level function using `Class.getResourceAsStream()`.

Is there any way to get a reference to the class that the top level function will be compiled into so that I can write, for example

```
val myThing = readFromStream(MYCLASS.getResourceAsStream(...))
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another way I found is to declare a local class or an anonymous object inside a top level function and to get its `enclosingClass`:

```
val topLevelClass = object{}.javaClass.enclosingClass
```

<sup>Note: to work, this declaration should be placed on top level or inside a top-level function.</sup>

Then you can use the `topLevelClass` as a `Class<out Any>`:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(topLevelClass) // class MyFileNameKt
}
```

Comment: Are there any advantages to this over just getting the class of the anonymous object?

Comment: In regards of loading the resources, no, there's not. But this is actually the way to get the top level class reflection, which one could need apart from resources.

Answer (score 17):

With Java 7 you can get a reference to the current Java class from a top level function using

```
MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass()
```

Comment: This is a question about Kotlin

Comment: Yes you are correct. Unfortunately SO won't let me upvote it unless an edit is made.

Comment: Upvoted. The anonymous object approach seems like a hack.

Answer (score 12):

No, there is no syntax to reference that class. You can access it using Class.forName(). For example, if the file is called "Hello.kt" and is located in the package "demo", you can obtain the class by calling `Class.forName("demo.HelloKt")`.

Answer (score 6):

In the absence of a way to get a reference directly, I've fallen back on creating an anonymous object in the current package

```
val myThing = object: Any() {}.javaClass.getResourceAsStream(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

As linters like [detekt](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt) would flag anonymous classes as `EmptyClassBlock` you could also use something like

```
internal object Resources

fun resourceStream(name: String): InputStream {
    return Resources.javaClass.getResourceAsStream(name)
}
```