# Access classloader from main method (package method)

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to access a ressource (certificate) in my classloader.

```
fun main() {
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore",  this.javaClass.getResource("/certi.jks").path)

}
```

But I can't because it's a package method.
As a workaround I put the code in a class method and I make a new class to set those.

Any better way to do that ?

Comment: By ‘package method’ do you mean a [top-level function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope), defined directly in a file outside of a class? — If so, this looks rather like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951894/is-there-a-way-to-reference-the-java-class-for-a-kotlin-top-level-function).

Comment: Yeah you are right it's a duplicate. Thx.